# Python 2.5 ElementTree handle xml node with namespace

Tags: python, xpath, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I'm using Python2.5, ElementTree 1.2 to parse XML document, which looks like:

```
<cm:CompositeMessage xmlns:cm="http://www.xyz.com">
    <cm:Message>
        <cm:Body format="text/xml">
            <CHMasterbook >
                    <event>
                            <eventName>Snapshot</eventName>
                            <date>2013-10-25</date>
                            <time>20:59:02</time>
                    </event>
            </CHMasterbook>
         </cm:Body>
     </cm:Message>
</cm:CompositeMessage>
```

After I register the namespace

```
ET._namespace_map['http://www.xyz.com'] = 'cm'
```

I can parse the XMLdocument and locate the 'event' node

```
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(xml))
tree.findall('./{http://www.xyz.com}Message/{http://www.xyz.com}Body/CHMasterBook/event')
```

But if 'CHMasterbook' node has namespaces like

```
<CHMasterbook xmlns="http://uri.xyz.com/Chorus/Message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://uri.xyz.com/Chorus/Message ../schema/chorus-master-book-msg.xsd">
```

tree.findall only returns empty list and it can no longer locate 'event' node. I also tried to register those namespaces like:

```
ET._namespace_map['http://uri.xyz.com/Chorus/Message'] = 'xmlns'
ET._namespace_map['http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'] = 'xmlns:xsi'
ET._namespace_map['http://uri.xyz.com/Chorus/Message ../schema/chorus-master-book-msg.xsd'] = 'xsi:schemaLocationi'
```

But it didn't help.

I can only use Python 2.5 and ElementTree 1.2 (can't use lxml). Does anyone know how to locate the 'event' node with 'CHMasterbook' having those namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(xml))
tree.findall('./{http://www.xyz.com}Message'
             '/{http://www.xyz.com}Body'
             '/{http://uri.xyz.com/Chorus/Message}CHMasterbook'
             '/{http://uri.xyz.com/Chorus/Message}event')
```

In your example, you use `CHMasterbook` and sometimes `CHMasterBook`. Remember case is important in XML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for me. CHMasterbook is a typo, and should be CHMasterBook.